# Replacing sub-string of a String with another String in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep)
{
    static char buffer[4096];
    char *p;

    if(!(p = strstr(str, orig))) // Is 'orig' even in 'str'?
        return str;

    strncpy(buffer, str, p-str);

    // Copy characters from 'str' start to 'orig' st$
    buffer[p-str] = '\0';
    sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", rep, p+strlen(orig)); // <-- here

    return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
    puts(replace_str("Hello, world!", "world", "Miami"));
    return 0;
}
```

How this code work, please explain thoroughly...
I am not able to recognize the working of `p+strlen(orig)`.

Comment: More context please? Is `p` the location in the original string that we're replacing? Is str or orig the original string? Or is orig the string we're replacing inside str? I assume you've copied str/orig into buffer first?

Comment: yeah .... but still not able to recognise how pointer working in this code

Comment: Please show us more code around that line.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep)
{
  static char buffer[4096];
  char *p;

  if(!(p = strstr(str, orig)))  // Is 'orig' even in 'str'?
    return str;

  strncpy(buffer, str, p-str); // Copy characters from 'str' start to 'orig' st$
  buffer[p-str] = '\0';

  sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", rep, p+strlen(orig));

  return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
  puts(replace_str("Hello, world!", "world", "Miami"));

  return 0;
}

Comment: @AakashJohari I edited your answer, to include your code. please review it.

Comment: @ikh thanx a lot .... actualy m new here

Comment: but please explain how this working

Comment: sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", rep, p+strlen(orig));

Comment: i mean how pointer is used in appending string?

Comment: [You should search and research before asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and show your effort in your question. Moreover, it's not good to ask and rush by comment. Instead, edit your answer and just wait for answers to you. Anyway, I'll write the answer; please wait >o<

Comment: .. well, already there exists a answer >o< if the answer is helpful for you, please "accept" it by clicking "check" button beside the body of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sprintf` command has the following declaration:

```
sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

your declaration in question is:

```
sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", rep, p+strlen(orig));
```

The sprintf command writes to the character pointer `str`, the values `rep` and `p+strlen(orig)` in accordance with the format string `"%s%s"`. Essentially, it is simply combining (or concatenating) `rep` and `p+strlen(orig)` in `buffer+(p-str)`.

Note that `str` (in the `sprintf declaration`) is of type `char *` meaning that `buffer+(p-str)` must also be type `char *` (a character pointer). `buffer` has a pointer address, say `1000` as an example. To that address, we will add the difference `p-str` (say 25). So the `sprintf` command will combine the two strings `rep` and `p+strlen(orig)` in memory beginning at the address `1000 + 25 = 1025`

We also know from the format string `"%s%s"` that both `rep` and `p+strlen(orig)` will likewise be type `char *` pointers. The address of `rep` is whatever it is, but the next `char *` pointer `p+strlen(orig)` will be `p` (say 1500) + `strlen(orig)` (the length of `orig` assume is `20 chars`. So `sprintf` will read the string value beginning at address `1520` along with the string `rep` into `buffer` at address `buffer+(p-str)` (or 1025 for this example).

Lets say the pointers point to the following strings:

```
rep = "In the beginning"
  p = "the sky was blue and there was light!"
```

Lets also say that `strlen(orig) = 20`

```
  p+strlen(orig) = p[20] = " there was light!"
```

So the resulting string in buffer at (my fake address 1025) is:

```
buffer+(p-str) = "In the beginning there was light!"
```

Comment: If it helps, don't forget to "Accept" my answer by clicking the box next to the number at the top left of the answer. Glad I could help.